# Falha de autenticação - Google Maps Api

Tags: android, api, maps

Olá.

Desde a última semana venho tendo um problema com a minha aplicação que usa o Google Maps API V2.

Simplesmente, a minha chave parou de funcionar. Depois disso já criei novas chaves e não funciona mais.

Já alterei as chaves e desinstalei a aplicação do dispositivo antes de reinstalar e nada.

Por favor, preciso de ajuda! É parte do meu TCC e tenho que mostrá-lo funcionando hoje a noite.

Comment: E qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso? Por favor, já tentei e não encontrei a forma de fazer.

Comment: Poste seu código, retorna algum erro na aplicação?

Comment: @PedroAugusto v3 é javascript, não se aplica para Android.

Comment: Realmente. Não me atentei a isso

Comment: Problema resolvido adicionando uma permissão para mapreceive e o uses-feature do GL